# hibernate option in xubuntu (22:04) logout menu

Tags: xubuntu, hibernate

I have a swapfile, which happens to be larger than my RAM, and the "Power Management" settings allows be to select "Hibernate" for various button presses... and for various power-saving modes (so `xfce4-power-manager` **is** installed)

How do I add it as a user-chosen action... presumable from the *logout* menu?

- I can `shutdown` - except I don't want to close all my apps
- I can `suspend` - except that just writes current-state to RAM

  - and the computer doesn't actually shut down
  - and the computer runs out of battery overnight, and everything gets closed/lost

I want to be able to `hibernate` - which is that state between the two.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you added a `resume` option to your grub configuration? This is required when using a swap file with hibernation, and may be why you don't see the option in your menu 

Comment: I followed https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/ - and the relevant details are in `/etc/default/grub`